# (Yii2) submitButton =>Converting onclick function to siteControllers?

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

**index.php**

```
<?php  use yii\helpers\Html; ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('tew',

['class' => 'btn btn-primary',

'onClick'=>'buttonClicked']) ?>
```

**siteController.php**

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        if($buttonClicked)
           {

        echo "Button Clicked";

}
        return $this->render('index');
```

So how to call button click function in siteContoller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need  check a specific submit button you must name it  and assign a value 
You can obtain the submit this way

```
 'value'=>'create_add', 'name'=>'submit'
    <?= Html::submitButton('tew',['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 
            'value'=>'my_value', 'name'=>'submit',
          'onClick'=>'buttonClicked']) ?>
```

then in your controller you can check the if specific button is clicked

```
public function actionIndex()
{
   if (Yii::$app->request->post('submit')==='my_value') {
      echo "Button my_value Clicked";
   } 
   return $this->render('index');
}
```

In your case you must add  the value

```
<?php  

use yii\helpers\Html; 

?>

<?= Html::submitButton('tew',['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 
                'value' => 'my_value', // you must add  a proper value to check in action 
                'onClick'=>'buttonClicked']) ?>
```

Comment: The action in controller is executed  server side when you form is submitted ...not locally in the browser .. in your code you invoce a function buttonClicked when clik event happen ..  then try remove the 'onClick'=>'buttonClicked'  form your button code .. (could be you don't have a proper buttonClicked  function and the code fails ) ... check in your browser  console what happen after the click  ..

Comment: In browser console after click "uncaught referenceerror buttonClicked is not defined"

Comment: as expected .. you have a call for a function that not exist .. then you have two choice  .. or you remove the code  'onClick'=>'buttonClicked' from you buttom and so the php code is called  and executed .. or you add  a proper javascript function named buttonClicked() and do what do you want inside this function ..  hope this is clear ..

Comment: siteController.php => public function actionAdd(){
        echo "asdasdasdasd";
    }

index.php =>  <?= Html::submitButton('tew',[
    'id'=>'q1',
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
    ]) ?>     
   
   ajax.js=> <?= Html::submitButton('tew',[
    'id'=>'q1',
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
    ]) ?>

Comment: sorry that was mistake

Comment: I tried to call function from siteController:=>public function actionHello(){echo "Hello"; return $this->render('index');} As you said I use javascript function js2.js=>$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#q1").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url  : 'hello'

        });
    });

}); index.php => <?= Html::submitButton('tew',[ 'id'=>'q1', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary', ]) ?> but it also not working....maybe wrong url in js2.js

Comment: public function actionIndex()
{
   if (Yii::$app->request->post('submit')==='my_value') {
      echo "Button my_value Clicked";
   } 
   return $this->render('index');
} this was your code . But "if" not working here

Comment: you must add  the proper  value to your submit button  .. answer udpated

Comment: It works but after updating page it shows "The page that you're looking for....". And shows the message  even I did not click.

Comment: i suggest you of post a new properly documented   question with your actual code and the problem you have now  . .. if the code provided  work  then  mean that your original question  is solved ..